# How to do calculated fields in peewee?

Tags: python, peewee

How might one make a calculated field in a model definition?  Is it possible to perform the calculation inside the generated sql query?  The following `fruit_difference` would be the member in the peewee model I want to achieve.

```
SELECT
    apple_count,
    orange_count,
    (apple_count - orange_count) fruit_difference
FROM fruit_vendors
```

Comment: As I see the answer below isn't sufficient, I mean, yes this will works when accesing from instance, but every access makes new request to db, I was also wondering how can we write something like `(apple_count - orange_count) fruit_difference as diff` and just use the returned diff value directly from the main querry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is a property. If you use the Python built in property, it will be evaluated in Python. If you want to do it on Database level, I guess you should use [Hybrid Property](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#hybrid).

This is a good example from the documentation:

```
class Interval(Model):
    start = IntegerField()
    end = IntegerField()

    @hybrid_property
    def length(self):
        return self.end - self.start

    @hybrid_property
    def radius(self):
        return abs(self.length) / 2

    @radius.expression
    def radius(cls):
        return fn.ABS(cls.length) / 2
```

> What is neat is that both the radius implementations refer to the
>   length hybrid attribute! When accessed via an Interval instance, the
>   radius calculation will be executed in Python. When invoked via an
>   Interval class, we will get the appropriate SQL.

Comment: where is hybrid_property imported from??

Comment: @SkyWalker
`from playhouse.hybrid import hybrid_property`